# Minimum distance between two circles along a specified vector on a cartesian plane

Tags: vector, geometry, 2d, collision

I am trying to solve the following problem (I am using Matlab, though pseudo-code / solutions in other languages are welcome):

I have two circles on a Cartesian plane defined by their centroids (p1, p2) and their radii (r1, r2). circle 1 (c1 = [p1 r1]) is considered 'dynamic': it is being translated along the vector V = [0 -1]. circle 2 (c2 = [p2 r2]) is considered 'static': it lies in the path of c1 but the x component of its  centroid is offset from the x component of c2 (otherwise the solution would be trivial: the distance between the circle centroids minus the sum of their radii).

I am trying to locate the distance (d) along V at which circle 1 will 'collide' with circle 2 (see the linked image). I am sure that I can solve this iteratively (i.e. translate c1 to the bounding box of c2 then converge / test for intersection). However, I would like to know if there is a closed form solution to this problem.

Comment: Link to image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/au1jqcpnnl763hr/circdist.png?dl=0

Comment: This is a maths question not a programming question.  Try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift coordinates to simplify expressions

```
px = p1.x - p2.x
py = p1.y - p2.y
```

And solve quadratic equation for `d` (zero, one, or two solutions)

```
px^2 + (py - d)^2 = (r1 + r2)^2
(py - d)^2 = (r1 + r2)^2 - px^2
d = py +/- Sqrt((r1 + r2)^2 - px^2)
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

As the question title does not match the question and accepted answer which is dependent on a fixed vector {0, -1}, or {0, 1} rather than an arbitrary vector I have added another solution that works for any unit vector.

Where (See diagram 1)

- `dx`, `dy` is the unit vector of travel for circle `c1`
- `p1`, `p2` the centers of the moving circle `c1` and static circle `c2`
- `r1`, `r2` the radius of each circle

The following will set `d` to the distance `c1` must travel along `dx`, `dy` to collide with `c2` if no collision the d will be set to `Infinity`

There are three cases when there is no solution

1. The moving circle is moving away from the static circle. `u < 0`
2. The moving circle never gets close enough to collide. `dSq > rSq`
3. The two circles are already overlapping. `u < 0` luckily the math makes
   this the same condition as moving away.

   **Note** that if you ignore the sign of `u` (1 and 3) then `d` will be the distance to first (causal) contact going backward in time

Thus the pseudo code to find `d`

```
d = Infinity
rSq = (r1 + r2) ^ 2     
u = (p1.x - p2.x) * dx + (p1.x - p2.x) * dy 
if u >= 0
    dSq = ((p2.x + dx * u) - p1.x) ^ 2 + ((p2.y + dy * u) - p1.y) ^ 2
    if dSq <= rSq 
        d = u - (rSq - dSq) ^ 0.5
```

The point of contact can be found with

```
cpx = p1.x + dx * d;
cpy = p1.x + dy * d;
```

### <sub>Diagram 1</sub>

[image: Diagram 1 showing variables and their relationship to the problem]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what software did you use to create the diagram?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson In-house animation utilities I wrote some time back.